# Is there a quick way to go to the top or the bottom of a web page when using the standard internet browser

Tags: browser, navigation

Browsing to a **long page** in the **standard browser** on my *Galaxy S* phone, I just realised how hard it is to go back to the top of the page ( after having scrolled to the end ).

Is there a way ( *some gesture or something* ) to simulate the **'Home'** and **'End'** keys one can use when using a PC browser programs ? E.g. to quickly go to the top or the end of the page ?

Comment: You could zoom all the way out and zoom back in at the top ... not ideal I know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but this can easily be done using gestures in Dolphin Browser HD.

Comment: Have to try the Dolphin browser again than ... did so a couple of months ago when I first got my mobile, but wasn't that impressed with it. Maybe it was because of the lag-problem with my Samsung (at the time - that's much better now I upgraded to Froyo 2.2.1). Can't remember why I uninstalled Dolphin it. But I will give it a try again ... thx

Comment: I abandoned it after the first time I tried it too, but after I tried it again and got used to it, I can't browse without it.